# Are read replicas in Amazon affected by updates in master?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

**This is my problem:**

*Sometimes one long lasting query (>60 secs, and I have a lot of those) which is always a SELECT makes my whole application stops working properly up until the query is solved.*

*The first long lasting query starts making the others slow and then all the system is freezed.*

---

My app is a Rails 3.2 application with ruby 2.3.

I use Makara as adapter for read replicas.

I have the following architecture:

- 5 medium.t2 EC2 instances that performs SELECTS
- 1 medium.t2 EC2 instance that performs INSERTS
- 1 MariaDB server + 2 read replicas. InnoDB Engine.

I have four resources:

- 1 api to update the database, INSERT
- 1 index with conditions, SELECT
- 1 count action with conditions, SELECT
- 1 autocomplete, SELECT

My server stack uses Apache + Passenger.

**This is my guess:**

*The read replica is trying to update a table that is actually being used by a select operation, consequently he is unable to apply the sync until the app finishes, making both read replicas different from the master.*

**Best part:**

*We only deal with 400 rpm and the half of them are to update results in the database.*

Comment: Which storage engine you are using. MyISAM has only a full table Lock. so if you modify a table in the "long running queries** no other taks can read this table and must wait unit finished the first query. change to InnoDB, there is a row lock that only locks the changing rows

Comment: InnoDB, updating answer. And long running queries are only SELECT queries.

Comment: sorry you wrote it in your question, my mistake

Comment: Rails is single threaded so performing a long running query will by default "block" your app as you put it.  Have you considered using a background job to handle the longer running queries?  Is it possible to optimize your select queries so they don't take so long?

Comment: Rails server is default, but Passenger is not. And each one spawns a Ruby Interpreter so locked threads are not the problem.

Comment: what is the pool size?

Comment: do you really need such long queries?

Comment: If locking from updates actions was a problem you would see long running update queries. You can use `show engine status INNODB` to get more info about what is going on.

Comment: One of the instances is only making the updates while the other 5 are performing the selects. The updates are not slowed at all.